# Java animation won't move

Tags: java, file, animation, filereader

I'm trying to make my 3 characters do the 10 commands that are in the text file I made. The commands consist of 3 types of actions: MOVETO, TURNTO, and PLAY (sound file). When I run the program, the characters appear, but they don't move at all. How can I fix this?

I have 3 different classes:

```
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Cmd {
        ArrayList<String> action;//stores whether TURNTO, MOVETO
        ArrayList<String> params;

        int nCmds;


        Cmd(){
            nCmds=0;
            action=new ArrayList<String>();
            params=new ArrayList<String>();
        }

        boolean cmdRead(String fname) throws FileNotFoundException{
            Scanner fs = new Scanner(new FileReader(fname));

            while(fs.hasNext()){
                String act=fs.next();
                if(act.equals("MOVETO") || act.equals( "TURNTO") || act.equals("PLAY")){
                    nCmds+=1;
                    action.add(act);
                    params.add(fs.nextLine().trim());
                }

            }

            fs.close();
            if( nCmds > 0){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }

        String getAction(){
            if(nCmds>0){
                return action.get(0);
            }else{
                return "";
            }
        }
        String getParam(){
            if(nCmds>0){
                return params.get(0);
            }else{
                return "";
            }
        }
        boolean advance(){
            if(nCmds >0){
                nCmds--;
                action.remove(0);
                params.remove(0);

            }
            if(nCmds>0){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }

        } 
    }




import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Actor {
    private EZImage img;            // Member variable to store bug picture
    private int x, y, startx, starty;   // Member variables to store x, y, startx, starty
    private int destx, desty;           // Member variables to store destination values
    private long starttime;             // Member variable to store the start time
    private long duration;              // Member variable to store the duration
    private boolean interpolation;      // Member variable that is set to true if it is in the interpolation state

    // ********* ROTATE
    private float currRot= 0;
    private float destRot = 0;
    private float startRot = 0;
    private boolean interpolationRot;

    private boolean hasCmd;
    private Cmd cmds;

    // Constructor for character takes 3 parameters
    public Actor(String filename,int posx, int posy){

        // Set the current position of the character
        x=posx;y=posy;

        // Create the image of the bug
        img = EZ.addImage(filename, posx, posy);
        img.scaleTo(0.5);
        // Move it to the starting position. This is actually redundant.
        img.translateTo(x,y);

        // Set interpolation mode to false initially
        interpolation = false;
        interpolationRot = false;

        //(1)initialize hasCmd, and cmds object
        hasCmd=false;
        cmds=new Cmd();
    }
    public void readCmd(String fname) throws FileNotFoundException{
        //(2) Read a file using the cmds variable
        hasCmd=cmds.cmdRead(fname);

    }
    public void setCmd(){
        //(3) Go through cmds variable and set next command
        String action=cmds.getAction();

        String parameters=cmds.getParam();

        String []params=parameters.split(" ");

        int x,y,ang,dur;

        switch(action) {
        case "PLAY":
            EZSound sound=EZ.addSound(params[0]);
            sound.play();
            break;
        case"MOVETO":
            x=Integer.parseInt(params[0]);
            y=Integer.parseInt(params[1]);
            dur=Integer.parseInt(params[2]);
            setDestination(x,y,dur);
            break;
        case"TURNTO":
            ang=Integer.parseInt(params[0]);
            dur=Integer.parseInt(params[1]);
            setRot(ang,dur);
            break;

        default:
        }
        hasCmd=cmds.advance();
    }


    // Set the destination by giving it 3 variables
    // Dur means duration and is measured in seconds
    public void setDestination(int posx, int posy, long dur){

        // Set destination position and duration
        // Convert seconds to miliseconds
        destx = posx; desty = posy; duration = dur*1000;

        // Get the starting time (i.e. time according to your computer)
        starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // Set the starting position of your bug
        startx=x; starty=y;

        // Set interpolation mode to true
        interpolation = true;

    }

    // ********* Set our Rotation
    public void setRot(float s, float dur){
        destRot = s;
        starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        duration = (long) (dur*1000);
        startRot = currRot;
        interpolationRot = true;
    }

    // If youÊ»re in an interpolation state or have commands to process then return true, else false.
    public boolean moving() {
        //(4)return whether object is in process of moving or there are commands in the queue
        return (interpolation || interpolationRot || hasCmd);
    }

    public boolean hasCmd(){
        return hasCmd;
    }
    // This moves the character based on the current time and elapsed time according to the interpolation equation
    public void go(){

        // If interpolation mode is true then do interpolation
        if (interpolation == true) {

            // Normalize the time (i.e. make it a number from 0 to 1)
            float normTime = (float) (System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime)/ (float) duration;

            // Calculate the interpolated position of the bug
            x = (int) (startx + ((float) (destx - startx) *  normTime));
            y = (int) (starty + ((float) (desty - starty) *  normTime));

            // If the difference between current time and start time has exceeded the duration
            // then the animation/interpolation is over.
            if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime) >= duration) {

                // Set interpolation to false
                interpolation = false;

                // Move the character all the way to the destination
                x = destx; y = desty;
            }
            // Don't forget to move the image itself.
            img.translateTo(x,y);   
        }else if (interpolationRot == true){
            // Normalize the time (i.e. make it a number from 0 to 1)
            float normTime = (float) (System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime)/ (float) duration;

            // Calculate the interpolated position of the bug
            currRot =  (startRot + ((float) (destRot - startRot) *  normTime));


            // If the difference between current time and start time has exceeded the duration
            // then the animation/interpolation is over.
            if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime) >= duration) {

                // Set interpolation to false
                interpolationRot = false;

                // Scale the character all the way to the destination
                currRot = destRot;
            }
            // DonÊ»t forget to move the image itself.
            img.rotateTo(currRot);  
        }else if (hasCmd){
            //(5) if there is a command left set it
            setCmd();
        }

    }
}




import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Animation {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Setup EZ graphics system.
        EZ.initialize(1024, 1024);

        // Set background color to dark green
        EZ.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

        //(6) Make characters 
        Actor monkey=new Actor("monkey2.png",500,500);
        Actor pikachu=new Actor("pikachu-0.png", 300,500);
        Actor luigi=new Actor("Luigi.png", 700,500);


        //(7) read commands from files
        monkey.readCmd("Monkey.txt");
        pikachu.readCmd("Pikachu.txt");
        luigi.readCmd("Luigi.txt");

        //(8) reanimate them!
        while(monkey.moving()) {
            monkey.go();
        }
        while (pikachu.moving()) {
            pikachu.go();
        }
        while (luigi.moving()) {
            luigi.go();
        }
        EZ.refreshScreen();

    }

}
```